# Help to Understand and fix mysql error message Integrity violation: 1452

Tags: mysql

BTW I am using zendframework,doctrine 1.2 and MYSQL

//error
Message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gepm2`.`Regions`, CONSTRAINT `Regions_id_Districts_regions_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `Districts` (`regions_id`))

The thing is I am storing the data into the Regions table and these area the values [
id:AR,
name:Test Name,
Countries_id: UK]

```
enter code here


##YAML
Country:
 tableName: Countries
 columns:
   id:
    type: string(3)
    fixed: true
    primary: true
    notnull: true
   name:
    type: string(45)
    default: null
   currency:
    type: string(3)
    fixed: true
    default: null

Region:
 tableName: Regions
 columns:
  id:
    type: string(2)
    fixed: true
    primary: true
    notnull: true
  name:
    type: string(45)
    default: null
  Countries_id:
    type: string(3)
    fixed: true
    primary: true
    notnull: true
  relations:
  country:
    class: Country
    local: Countries_id
    foreign: id
    foreignAlias: regions
    foreignType: many
    owningSide: true
 indexes:
  fk_Regions_Countries:
  fields: [Countries_id]

District:
 tableName: Districts
 columns:
  id:
   type: string(3)
   fixed: true
   primary: true
   notnull: true
 name:
   type: string(45)
   default: null
 Regions_id:
   type: string(2)
   fixed: true
   primary: true
   notnull: true
 relations:
  region:
   class: Region
   local: Regions_id
   foreign: id
   foreignAlias: districts
   foreignType: many
   owningSide: true
 indexes:
 fk_Districts_Regions1:
   fields: [Regions_id]
```

Answer (score 2):

> I used a Identifying Relationship instead of a Non-Identifying Relationship

where is the difference?

Here is my Solution. The problem is like above.

```
$offer = $offerTbl->createRow(array('idcandidate'=>14));
$offer->save();
```

when I create a new row I give also FK from referenced table

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure this out. I used MySQL Workbench and got the relationship specification wrong. I used a Identifying Relationship instead of a Non-Identifying Relationship. Hope this helps someone.